# Using .NET Core DI with runtime parameters?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've created a simple `Echo` class (for cimplicity) with `IEcho`  Interface :

```
 public interface IEcho
    {
        string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Echo : IEcho
    {
        public Echo(string s  )
        {
            Value = s;
        }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Basically , it will return the same value as provided in ctor.

I'm registering it as :

```
public IEcho Echo { get; }

private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<IEcho >(a=>new Echo("Hey"));
    }
```

And indeed it works :

[image]

**Question:**

The `"Hey"` value was supplied in compile time.

How can I send the `"Hey"` value in runtime rather compile time ?

Comment: Do you know about the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` package? `IOptions<>` is the standard way of passing in strongly-typed configuration for ASP.Net core.

Comment: Who said i'm using configuration access ? 

Comment: Uh...that's why I'm asking. Based on your register method you're using asp.net core, which has an `IConfiguration` property. You can use `serviceCollection.Configure<>()`. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @gunr2171 Sorry , I guess I'm not following you . Can you please elaborate how `IOptions` can help here ?

Comment: He's saying that, instead of hardcoding "hey" into your program, you can retrieve it from a configuration file.

Comment: You don't need to use configuration access to use `IOptions<T>` or `Options<T>`. `services.AddScoped<IOptions<Echo>>(Options.Create(new Echo("Hey")));` For runtime, you'll just have to change the value in code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see. But I wrote in the question , `in runtime` so it can be considered that `hey` value come from web request or something

Comment: Then use a web request.  It's just a string.  Replace "hey" with whatever variable you want that contains the string you want.

Comment: In that case you wouldn't want your string value going into the constructor, you'd want it as a parameter for the service method you're calling. What is running the `Echo` service? When you're using DI services you're not allowed to touch the constructor chain.

Comment: _When you're using DI services you're not allowed to touch the constructor chain_ Oh I didn't know that @gunr2171 . So I guess I should rethink about my actions

Comment: If you want to inject a runtime value, just define the interface or delegate that would return it. The implementation would be something that can supply that runtime value. The runtime value isn't something you would inject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `IEchoFactory` and inject it.

```
interface IEchoFactory
{
    IEcho GetEcho( string text );
}

class EchoFactory : IEchoFactory
{
    public IEcho GetEcho(string text)
    {
        return new Echo(text);
    }
}


serviceCollection.AddTransient<IEchoFactory, EchoFactory>();
```

And in the code that received the injection, instead of

```
var t = _echo.Value;  //Assuming _echo is populated via injection
```

use

```
var e = _echoFactory.GetEcho("String determined at runtime"); 
var t = e.Value;
```

Comment: Why inject it if you're accessing the class directly via `EchoFactory.GetEcho` ? Or am I just misunderstanding that for the variable name.

Comment: In the OP's example, it appears he has a variable named `Echo` that points to an instance. I was following that pattern. But it's not clear, so I'll change the case.